# Add scroll-bar in EditableGrid

Tags: jquery, grid, vertical-scroll, editablegrid

I am using EditableGrid(http://www.editablegrid.net) and wanted to know that is there a way to insert a scroll-bar within the grid.

I don't want to use pagination, I just want to add a scroll-bar, so that I can scroll down/up to view the records.

Say, I set the pagesize of the grid to 20, and if there are 40th records/rows to be displayed, then a vertical scroll-bar appears to the right of the grid. If it is '<= 20' then it should not show the scroll-bar.

Answer (score 0):

you would set the pagesize to infinite (bad idea) then you simply limit the size of the table that you are binding your DataTable too.  This will limit the size of the DataTable and make it look "good" for less than 20 and more than 20 won't look different it will just have a scroll bar.

This isn't a recommended plan of attack as this means a lot of items in the DOM and in your dataTable at once, you should use pagination or the all records in JSON methods.

Let me know if you need more information.